# Microsoft Graph API and SharePoint files permissions

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I try with no success to give read or write access to an existing user (Office 365) on a Sharepoint drive folder.

With Graph Explorer the URL is like :

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drive/items/{folder id}/permissions`

I can get actual permissions with `GET` method, but with `POST` method and this body I've got Invalid Request :

```
{
    "grantedToV2": {
        "user": {
            "id": "xxxxxxx",
            "displayName": "xxx xxx"
        }
    },
    "roles": [
        "read"
    ]
}
```

I tried with the powershell SDK and the New-MgDriveItemPermission too with no success.

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add permissions to an you will have to make a `POST` request to the below endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/invite
```

With the body containing all the info about the invitation request as the below example:

```
{
  "requireSignIn": false,
  "sendInvitation": false,
  "roles": [ "read | write"],
  "recipients": [
    {
        "email": "{email of the user}"
    }
 ],
  "message": "string"
}
```

If your request is succesful the response you will get back will be of the below format:

`Status: 200`

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
            "id": "<some id>",
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "grantedTo": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "<user>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "<some id>",
                    "displayName": "<user's display name>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

}

Below I will share with you the code snippet I got from Graph Explorer after creating a succesful request:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var recipients = new List<DriveRecipient>()
{
    new DriveRecipient
    {
        Email =  "<user>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
};

var message = "Here's the file that we're collaborating on.";

var requireSignIn = true;

var sendInvitation = true;

var roles = new List<String>()
{
    "write"
};

await graphClient.Sites["root"].Drive.Items["<folder-id>"]
    .Invite(recipients,requireSignIn,roles,sendInvitation,message,null,null,null)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

### Notes

1. You can find documentation about the endpoint [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
2. If you try to add permissions to a Folder that inherits its permission model from the document library, you should watch out because in some cases if the user is not a member of the site groups, MS Graph might invoke unique permissions on the folder.

Comment: Thanks, I understand better why I could not assign permissions.
Do you know which function of the powershell graph sdk corresponds to this call (like new-mguser, new-...) ?

Comment: Hi John, i think its the below one
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.files/invoke-mginvitedriveitem?view=graph-powershell-1.0

Answer (score 0):

We struggled with this too. Thanks to the answer of @jimas13 we found the correct PowerShell equivalent code to set permissions on a SharePoint Document Library using the GraphAPI:

#### Module 'Microsoft.Graph.Files'

```
$params = @{
    recipients     = @(
        @{
            email = 'bob@contoso.com'
        }
    )
    message        = "Here's the file that we're collaborating on."
    requireSignIn  = $true
    sendInvitation = $false
    roles          = @('read')
}
Invoke-MgInviteDriveItem -DriveId $drive.Id -DriveItemId $folder.id -BodyParameter $params
```

#### Module 'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication' without json

```
$params = @{
    Uri         = "v1.0/sites/$($site.Id)/drive/items/$($folder.id)/invite"
    # Uri         = "v1.0//drives/$($drive.Id)/items/$($folder.id)/invite"
    Body        = @{
            requireSignIn  = $true
            sendInvitation = $false
            roles          = @('read')
            recipients     = @(   
                @{
                    email = 'bob@contoso.com'
                }
            )
            message        = 'Granted read permissions on folder'
        }
    Method      = 'POST'
}
Invoke-MgGraphRequest @params
```

#### Module 'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication' with json

```
$params = @{
    Uri         = "v1.0/sites/$($site.Id)/drive/items/$($folder.id)/invite"
    # Uri         = "v1.0//drives/$($drive.Id)/items/$($folder.id)/invite"
    Body        = (@{
            requireSignIn  = $true
            sendInvitation = $false
            roles          = @('read')
            recipients     = @(   
                @{
                    email = 'bob@contoso.com'
                }
            )
            message        = 'Granted read permissions on folder'
        } | ConvertTo-Json)
    Method      = 'POST'
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}
Invoke-MgGraphRequest @params
```

These 3 examples are tested with PowerShell version `7.4` and Graph module version `2.16.0`